# Error in counting number of comparisons in selection sort

Tags: c++, c, selection-sort

I want to count the number of comparisons in selection sort algorithm:

In the usual algorithm, i introduced a counting-variable `cont`, and i have initialised it `cont=0`.

The code is:

```
    void selectionSort(int a[],int n)
{
    int i,j,min,cont;
    int tmp;
    cont=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        min=i;
        for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
            {

                if(a[j]<a[min])
                {min=j;

                }
                cont=cont+1;

            }
        tmp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[min];
        a[min]=tmp;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I apply this to a vector of dimension 4, say `a[1]=2,a[2]=1,a[3]=4,a[4]=3`
and then `print("%d",cont)`, **the output is `4200958`**, which are way too much comparisons, so where is the error here?

**EDIT: As @Arnold pointed out, i have corrected the mispelled initialisation of the vector, now the output is 4, which is incorrect as well, i'm expecting the result to be 6. So where is the error here?**

*Below the full code *edited*:*

```
    void selectionSort(int a[],int n)
{
    int i,j,min,cont;
    int tmp;
    cont=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        min=i;
        for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
            {

                if(a[j]<a[min])
                {min=j;

                }
                cont=cont+1;

            }
        tmp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[min];
        a[min]=tmp;
    }
}

int main()
{
int a[4],cont;
cont=0;

a[0]=2;
a[1]=1;
a[2]=4;
a[3]=3;
selectionSort(a,4);
printf("%d",cont);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Array index starts from 0, it should be like `a[0] = 2; a[1] = 1; a[2] = 4; a[3] = 3;`.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I have corrected my code, and now the output is 4, which is not correct, it should be 6. So 'Houston, we still have a problem'

Comment: `cont` in main, is not the `cont` in selectionSort. Are you familiar with how scoping in C++ or C works?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes,this is true, to correct the error I inserted the function printf("%d",count); in the function, so that when invoking it inside main() it will automatically print the (theoretically) correct result. Anyway, the output is now 10, which still is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the second loop from:

```
for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
```

to:

```
for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
```

you should remove the equal sign from the condition.